# Is there a way to use an angular service in a CLI application

Tags: android, angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I am starting with angular, and I have developed several services to query to the database (firestore). What I wanted to do is to develop a command line application that invokes that services and run specific tasks, for instance, massive loads of users.

What I've tried so far is very disappointing:

```
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig);
const firestore = getFirestore( app );


const main = async () => {
  console.log('hello');
}

main();
```

Apart from loading the configuration from firestore, nothing. I've tried to figure out how karma injects the dependencies in the services under test, but no luck for this part.

Is there a "proper" way to load an angular service in a command line application??

Comment: Hi Raul! Is there a particular reason you want run this as an Angular app on the command line? Maybe it would be easier to create a command line only app and not have to deal with the frontend part of Angular? Are you planning on displaying the data in the browser? Just trying to get a feel for what you are wanting to accomplish.

Comment: I am developing an application for the web, and that's fine. But, imagine I wanted to add 500 users programmatically to the application. I wanted a backend application to deal with such tasks. Or -for instance- make a deletion of a special document that I do not want to make a user interface for that, even it that user interface would be protected only for admins

Comment: This is better suited for a pure nodeJS app. That is easy to run command line.

Comment: Yes @MikeOne, but I wanted to reuse the services I've developed so far. And I am agree with you that developing again a pure node js application will be a good approximation, but I was wondering if it is a way to effectively reuse an angular service outside angular

Comment: Not really, at least nog with a lot of effort and hacks. And in general, hour services should be fairly simple so easy to duplicate. If you’d go for a nestjs app in an Nx monorepo together with your Angular app, you can at least re-use things like typing, models and statics between the 2 apps.